# Fetching Data based on Look up value from another List

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, choice-field

I have a small requirement , where in i have 2 lists say List A and List B.

In List B, i have a lookup column which is looking up to List A column.
 Now on selection of Lookup column value in List B i want to bring in another column value from List A and append it to a choice field or a text field and dynamically change the text field  to  drop down if it is possible.

Hope you can help me out on this!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, we can't save a dynamical value to choice field.

For your case, you could get data from list A by rest api and populate to a text field and save.

Sample code:
[image]

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //replace fields and list name as yours 
            $('select[Title="LookupParent"]').change(function () {
                var parentID=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('parent')/items?$filter=ID eq " + parentID + "",
                    type: "GET",
                    async: true,
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                    success: function (data) {                        
                        $('input[title="TextField"]').val(data.d.results[0].Title);
                    },
                    error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqxr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            })
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: in the above example, i have employee name in place of lookup parent, and based   on that information needs to be fetched. but i am unable to get the employee name from the other list which is in people picker.
I am trying to pick the data and add to textfield and dynamically change that to  dropdown. Could you kindly help me in the process to get names then maybe i can follow your answer give above.